# Acumos Installation

Tags: installation, acumos

need some help getting acumos running.
Have VM with Ubuntu 20.04.4
Followed flow-1 here: https://docs.acumos.org/en/latest/submodules/system-integration/docs/z2a/tl-dr.html#flow-1

[acumos-k8s-portal-be-569bf85dc-kx89b-shows pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11AQS.png)

When I go to https://localhost/ on VM, I get 504 gateway timeout - nginx

[gateway timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHc90.png)

Not sure where to look for the issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into the same issue, I havent resolved it on my local VM but got all all setup and working as follows:

So I used Oracle VirtualBox for my VM's with Ubuntu desktop 20.04.4 - the issue persists no matter what I tried, even tried Ubuntu 18 with same results.

My current solution:
Got an Ubuntu cloud server from Hetzner (ubuntu server 20.04), went thru the same process and it's all up and running :), just bizarre.

Not sure if different results will come from vmware, will give it a try sometime.

Cheers.